# Python SocketIO app not working with https

Tags: javascript, python, heroku, flask, socket.io

I deployed [this application](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask) on Heroku. It seems to work fine when i load the page on http but i have problems when loaded with https:

```
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

The server-side part of the app is made on Python, the frontend part with a Javascript file and an index.html file. This is what the JS looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //connect to the socket server.
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
    var numbers_received = [];

    //receive details from server
    socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
        console.log("Received number" + msg.number);
        //maintain a list of ten numbers
        if (numbers_received.length >= 10){
            numbers_received.shift()
        }            
        numbers_received.push(msg.number);
        numbers_string = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers_received.length; i++){
            numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + numbers_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
        }
        $('#log').html(numbers_string);
    });

});
```

I tried to change `var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');` with:

- `var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');`
- `var socket = io.connect('/');`
- `var socket = io.connect('https://link-of-my-heroku-app.com);`

But none of those worked, any advice?

Comment: Are you sure that this particular request to `/test` endpoint is the problem? Maybe you have something else? Have you checked it in the networking tab in the browser?

Comment: I only got a 'failed to load response data' there!

Comment: Hi @Jack022 did you find any solution for this, I am facing the same problem.